# Pulling Post Image Attachments in WordPress 3.9

Tags: images, attachments

For some reason the functions I'm using for pulling post images/attachments isn't working after updating to 3.9, has something changed in the way we pull attachments?

The code I'm using in single.php

```
<?php
$attachments = get_children(
array(
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID
));
if(count($attachments) > 1) { ?>
    <div id="slider" class="flexslider marB18">
        <?php ct_status(); ?>
                    <ul class="slides">
                        <?php ct_slider_images(); ?>
                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                    <?php ct_slider_images(); ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
<?php } else {
    ct_first_image_lrg();
} ?>
```

Image functions:

```
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Get the first image attached to the current post */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function ct_get_post_image() {
    global $post;
    $photos = get_children( array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'post_status' => 'inherit', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image', 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order ID'));
    if ($photos) {
        $photo = array_shift($photos);
        return wp_get_attachment_url($photo->ID);
    }
    return false;
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Display first image large */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function ct_first_image_lrg() {
    $photo = ct_get_post_image();
    if ($photo) { ?>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
        <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img_resize/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo ct_get_post_image() ?>&amp;w=945&amp;zc=1" />
    </a>
    <?php }
}

/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Display all images attached to listing */
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function ct_slider_images() {
    $photos = ct_get_images('full');
    if ($photos) {
        foreach ($photos as $photo) { ?>
            <li data-thumb="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img_resize/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $photo ?>&amp;w=500&amp;zc=1">
                <img class="photo" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img_resize/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $photo ?>&amp;h=400&amp;w=945&amp;zc=1" title="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
            </li>
        <?php }
    }   
}
```